# Operator call corresponds to a dot-qualified call which is not allowed on a nullable receiver error

Tags: kotlin

This code doesn't compile:

```
val map = mutableMapOf<Int, Int>()
ar.forEach{
    if(!map.containsKey(it)) {
        map[it] = 1
    } else {
        map[it] = map[it] + 1
    }
}
```

This is the compilation error:

> Operator call corresponds to a dot-qualified call 'map[it].plus(1)'
>   which is not allowed on a nullable receiver 'map[it]'.

Since the `mutableMap` I created is **not** having nullable parameters, I am wondering why do I need to add not null checks later on? This code passes:

```
 else map[it] = map[it]!! + 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `map[it]` might return null if there's no entry in the map corresponding to that key. Even though you checked by calling `containsKey` on the line before, that doesn't guarantee that when you call `map[it]` you'll get a value back, as another thread might update the map's contents in between those two calls.

Comment: ^ this explains well what the issue is, but to actually solve it, you might want to try to produce one expression that would give you the value you desire, in this case `map[it]?.plus(1) ?: 1`

Comment: You could also just change it to `ar.forEach { map[it] = map.getOrDefault(it, 0) + 1 }` to avoid nullability issues altogether.